# Module hfspllus not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic

Tags: hfs+

I was about to mount a .dmg file as an .iso file. When I typed the command `sudo modprobe hfspllus` it came up with this modprobe: `FATAL: Module hfspllus not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-42-generic`.

Answer (score 1):

HFS Plus or [hfs+](/questions/tagged/hfs%2b) is a journaling file system developed by Apple. It serves as the primary file system of macOS and OS X. Instead of `sudo modprobe hfspllus` the correct command to use is `sudo modprobe hfsplus`